# Move Azure VHD from Premium to Standard Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I have a VM that currently has the OS disk in Premium Storage -- I'd prefer that it use Standard Storage and my data disks use Premium Storage. That said, is there an easy method to move the existing VHD from Premium to Standard?

Comment: Very on-topic for a lot of developers. [Here's code](http://mikehardy.com/blog/2017/03/21/move-azure-vm-from-premium-to-standard-storage/) to accomplish just that.

Comment: Just had an AZ Support Chat session.  They said "that's not an option, however you can move your VM once you make a copy of it." and sent me these links:  [SO: Is it possible to downgrade a premium storage subscription while keeping Azure virtual machine intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807583/is-it-possible-to-downgrade-a-premium-storage-subscription-while-keeping-azure-v) and [Azure Suggestions: Downgrade storage instance from premium to lower tier](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33999307-downgrade-the-storage-instance-from-premium-to-low).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jdixon04,

We published an article which outlines step by step guide to migrate to Premium Storage here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-migration-to-premium-storage/). There is also a sample script at the end of the article if you wish to automate the flow. If you have multiple VMs to migrate, automation through PowerShell scripts will be helpful. Let us know if you need additional information.

Aung

Comment: Thanks, Aung. Can this be applied in reverse? My goal is to migrate an OS disk to Standard Storage that I accidentally created under Premium Storage.

Comment: I have not personally tested the reverse scenario, however, it should work with no or some minor modifications. Let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: Aung, I just gave this a shot using AzCopy. Unfortunately, the transfer fails, but AzCopy doesn't really provide any sort of detailed error. Although it failed, I can see a 0 byte image in the new destination, so it doesn't look like an access issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please email us the AzCopy command that you ran to ascl@microsoft.com. Please be sure to remove sensitive information.

Comment: Aung, I sent a message to that address, but received a message in return that I needed to be added to the group's list of approved senders.

Comment: Hi Jdixon04, Michael Curd from our team replied to your email with a recommendation. Let me know if you did not receive his email.

Comment: hi @jdixon04. Could you  achieve the migration. I need to do the same. If you did, can you provide more info.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to

1. delete the VM while preserving the disks
2. use AzCopy to copy the OS disk to Standard Storage
3. create a Premium Storage capable VM using the copied disk

This may be more trouble than it is worth. You can likely script it by downloading the configuration prior to deletion, doing the copy, then modify the configuration and create the new VM.