# Is it possible to downgrade a premium storage subscription while keeping Azure virtual machine intact?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine in the cloud at Microsoft Azure. Currently I have a premium storage subscription. I want to downgrade this subscription to a cheaper storage solution while leaving the virtual machine intact. Would this be possible?

Comment: You mean to say you have the VHD for Virtual Machine stored in a Premium Storage account. Correct?

Comment: I think that is correct. I have chosen a subscription with premium storage from the different profiles offered at set up of a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 6):

What you're trying to do is not supported today. Changing from `Premium` to `Standard` is not possible today.

What you have to do is copy the VHD from your `Premium` storage account to a new or existing `Standard` storage account and create a new Virtual Machine using that.

**UPDATE**

> Can I copy my installed software in that case as well?

Yes, when you copy your VHD all your installed software gets copied as well. So essentially you need not re-install your software in the new VM provided you created the VM by copying the VHD from one storage account to another.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please do a search for "copy vhd between storage accounts" and you will find some examples. You can use Azure PowerShell Cmdlets or AzCopy utility to copy VHD from one storage account to another. HTH.